# Check pen-drive is connected or not in android_q init.rc

Tags: android-source, android-10.0, android-usb

if pen-drive is connected ,We have to run some device testing application(it should not enter into android).

If pen-drive is not connected , android should be boot-up .
For this scenario,how can we check pen-drive is connected or not in  init.rc.